# Replace not working on data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove the hyphen from a value obtained from the data attribute of an element, and then use said value as the contents of the element. Here's what I've tried:

**HTML**

```
<div id="output" data-value="-17"></div>
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
$('#output').text(($('#output').data('value')).replace('-','');
```

I have also tried:

```
$('#output').text($('#output').data('value').replace('-','');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxmf5hqd/)

What am I doing wrong

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are assigning that new value back to the value

Comment: I just want to inject it directly as the element text without assigning it first

Comment: `$('#output').data('value')` returns a `Number`, not a string!

Comment: (for simplicity as that would mean extra lines of code for this hypothetical situation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `)` missing in your code, which is causing a Syntax Error. You can however use function overload for simplicity.

```
$('#output').text(function(_,txt) {
   return $(this).attr('data-value').replace('-','');
});
```

Also, you've not included the jQuery in the fiddle. Also, you would better use `attr`, which returns a `String` as `data` returns a `Number`, which you'll have to convert to `String` as `-17` is a `Number`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxmf5hqd/4/)

Comment: @isherwood yup. I was operating on text, which was empty. Rectified.

Comment: would you mind explaining the significance of the underscore as the first argument?

Comment: @Marc the first param, is an index, which isn't needed. So it's a practice to name it as `_` to indicate that it has been used just because, it has to be there(you know, because of order of parameters is important) and not because it is wanted in the code. Its just the preference.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it working as intended by substituting `.data('value')` with `.attr('data-value')` after reading your revised answer.

Comment: @Marc glad to have helped. Hope you've also understood why I used `_`

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets look a little mixed up, try this

```
$('#output').text($('#output').data('value').replace('-',''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a String

```
 $('#output').text(new String($('#output').data('value')).replace('-',''));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxmf5hqd/6/)**

Comment: Better to just do `+ ""`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#output').text(Math.abs($('#output').data('value')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output" data-value="-17"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#output").text($('#output').attr('data-value').replace(/-/g, ""));
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxmf5hqd/8/)**